# setting a variable and modifying it in the same statement in Ruby

Tags: ruby, variables

I run into a lot of situations where I'm modifying a variable with a method and setting it to that modified value e.g...

```
value = "string"
value.modify #=> "new string"
value #=> "string"
value = value.modify
value #=> "new string"
```

I noticed that many Ruby methods have a `value.modify!` varient that does just that.

Is there a shorthand in Ruby for doing `value = value.modify`?
Also if I was ever to make my own `modify!` method how would I go about implementing it?

Comment: IMO, functional style programming where methods do not mutate the object is preferable in general, and writing out `var = var.method` or similar isn't all that bad. There are bigger, worse code issues to worry about.

Comment: Ya, I could see how this could be a problem when debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on how the class is implemented.  These bang-methods are not really possible on immutable objects like Symbols or Fixnums.  For Enumerables like Arrays, there is a `replace()` method that lets you write any bang-method like this:

```
def bang()
  replace(this.non_bang)
end
```

If you look at the source of many bang-methods, you will see that normally the bang-methods contain the meat of the code and the non-bang methods simply call `dup()` or `clone()` on the object and then call the bang version of the method like this:

```
def non_bang(*args)
  clone.bang(*args)
end
```

Comment: Enumerables do not necessarily have a `replace` method, but strings do, so that might be useful to the OP.

Comment: Ahh good call, I know Strings and Arrays have `replace()` and just assumed it was everywhere.